# How get time from control node when is not included in hosts?

Tags: ansible

How can I get time/date from control node when is not included in hosts ?

Reason: I would like to export output from "patching  task" to local machine.
It is working now, but I would like to use timestamp folder for these exports.
And for security reason, I don't want include ansible node to hosts ( to avoid patahcing/reboot my ansible node)
Is there any option to get system date-time ?

I know that there is module:  ansible_date_time
but is there other option ?

```
- name: export
    local_action: copy content="{{ patch_output.stdout }}" dest="tmp/{{ inventory_hostname }}.log"
```

Thanks I used below option. Lookup date ( mydate)  before tasks running. But how also create folder with this timestamp before tasks execution ?
somthing like : "{{lookup('pipe', mkdir {{ mydate )}}"
Can I define some command to run before tasks, like vars ?

```
  vars
    mydate: "{{lookup('pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')}}"
  tasks:
```

Thanks for help, now I finally executed only once the date command,
but how can I register only date output to variable ?
Because now I get all this mess : `msg": "2023-03-10_07-10-52"`
I would like to use it as variable for my folder_name.

```
  tasks:

  - name: date
    debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') }}"
    run_once: True
    register: time_reg
    delegate_to: localhost
```

ok, issue solved with `time_reg.msg`

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I get time and date from Control Node when it is not included in hosts file?*

Since Ansible [Lookup plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html)

> *Like all [templating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_templating.html#playbooks-templating), lookups execute and are evaluated on the Ansible control machine.*

a quick and simple approach can be to use the [`pipe` lookup – read output from a command](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pipe_lookup.html). The [Examples](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pipe_lookup.html#examples) shows this already.

```yaml
- name: Result 'date' command
  debug:
    msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.pipe', 'date') }}"
```

---

> *I know that there is module: `ansible_date_time` ...*

These are [Ansible facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#ansible-facts) and that

> *are data related to your remote systems, including operating systems, IP addresses, attached filesystems, and more. You can access this data in the `ansible_facts` variable.*

Comment: i think you have a typo, adebug?

Answer (score 1):

The function [*strftime*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#handling-dates-and-times) always gives you the current time on the conroller

```yaml
  timestamp: "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'|strftime }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- name: Compare strftime and date on the controller
  hosts: test_11

  vars:

    timeformat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    timecommand: "date +'{{ timeformat }}'"
    timestamp: "{{ timeformat|strftime }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ lookup('pipe', timecommand) }}
          {{ timestamp }}

    - pause:
        seconds: 3

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ lookup('pipe', timecommand) }}
          {{ timestamp }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [Compare strftime and date on the controller] *******************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    2023-03-10 10:49:10
    2023-03-10 10:49:10

TASK [pause] *********************************************************************************
Pausing for 3 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    2023-03-10 10:49:13
    2023-03-10 10:49:13

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=5    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Q: ***"How can I register only output from the date command?"***

A: I read this question as 'registering' time that doesn't change during the play. Use *set_fact* to 'instantiate' any of the declarations. For example,

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _timecommand: "{{ lookup('pipe', timecommand) }}"
```

The value of *_timecommand* will stay constant.

---

Example of a playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- name: Compare strftime and date on the controller
  hosts: test_11

  vars:

    timeformat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
    timecommand: "date +'{{ timeformat }}'"
    timestamp: "{{ timeformat|strftime }}"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        _timecommand: "{{ lookup('pipe', timecommand) }}"

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ _timecommand }}
          {{ timestamp }}

    - pause:
        seconds: 3

    - debug:
        msg: |
          {{ _timecommand }}
          {{ timestamp }}
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [Compare strftime and date on the controller] *******************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    2023-03-10 17:38:51
    2023-03-10 17:38:51

TASK [pause] *********************************************************************************
Pausing for 3 seconds
(ctrl+C then 'C' = continue early, ctrl+C then 'A' = abort)
ok: [test_11]

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [test_11] => 
  msg: |-
    2023-03-10 17:38:51
    2023-03-10 17:38:54

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_11: ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: Aaah,you have  right, the time is changed, so how then solve this issue to create folder with timestamp_name  at beginning of start ansible playbook and export all needed output to this folder ?

Comment: Use [*pre_tasks*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#using-roles-at-the-play-level), prehaps?

Comment: I checked with pre_tasks but it still executed on all hosts, my goal is to execute local command "create folder" only ones at beginning.

Comment: If you want to create the folder on the controller set `delegate_to: localhost` and set `run_once: true`. See [Controlling where tasks run: delegation and local actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#controlling-where-tasks-run-delegation-and-local-actions).

Comment: Thanks Vladimir again, But how can I register only output from date command ?  I updated my Q

Comment: Use *set_fact* to 'instantiate' the variable. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all,
issue solved with this:

```
 tasks:

  - name: date
    debug:
      msg: "{{ lookup('ansible.builtin.pipe', 'date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S') }}"
    run_once: True
    register: time_reg
    delegate_to: localhost



  - name: Create local directory
    ansible.builtin.file:
      path: "{{ time_reg.msg }}"
      state: directory
    delegate_to: localhost
```